# Wordpress stylesheet enqueue / dequeue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've been trying to create a toggle between Light / Dark mode using 2 different stylesheets for that. Both stylesheets are registered in the functions.php file like this:

```html
function theme_register_styles() { 

    wp_register_style( 'first-stylesheet',    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.min.css' );
    
    wp_register_style( 'second-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style_light.min.css' );
    
    wp_enqueue_style('first-stylesheet');
    
    global $wp_styles; 
}
```

I've been trying to achieve it with this code but it does not work.

```html
button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (wp.styles.registered[stylesheets.first].queue) {

    wp.styles.registered[stylesheets.first].dequeue();
    
    wp.styles.registered[stylesheets.second].enqueue();
  }
   else {

    wp.styles.registered[stylesheets.second].dequeue();
    

    wp.styles.registered[stylesheets.first].enqueue();
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In order to enqueue a different CSS file, you need to trigger a page relaod. From the frontend there are limited ways to trigger a page reload and communicate with the WordPress backend (e.g. REST API, AJAX, form submission).

The best option is probably to enqueue both light and dark mode, but if you need to do it this way, one option is to use query strings to force a page reload and then use them to determine light/dark mode. Below is an example.

PHP

```
add_action('init', 'theme_register_mode_styles');

function theme_register_mode_styles()
{
    if (isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'dark') {
        wp_dequeue_style('first-stylesheet');
        wp_register_style('second-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('second-stylesheet');
    } else if (isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'light') {
        wp_dequeue_style('second-stylesheet');
        wp_register_style('first-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style_light.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('first-stylesheet');
    } else {
        wp_register_style('first-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style_light.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('first-stylesheet');
    }
}
```

JS/HTML

```
<script>
const queryString = window.location.search
const mode = new URLSearchParams(queryString).get('mode')
function changeMode() {
  if ( mode == "dark" ) {
    document.getElementById("css-change").href="?mode=light";
  }
  else if ( mode == "light" ) {
    document.getElementById("css-change").href="?mode=dark";
  }
}
</script>

<button><a onclick="changeMode()" id="css-change" href="?mode=dark">Toggle Dark/Light Mode</a></button>
```